# Error exporting PDF file in jupyter notebook: pgfkeys '/tcb/size' error

Tags: pdf, latex, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pdflatex

I'm trying to export a notebook from Jupyter as a PDF file and server dumps this error mesage:

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "['xelatex', './notebook.tex', '-quiet']" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, bu
lgarian, russian, ukrainian, loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.de
f)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf-vi
a-dvi.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65
.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18
.sty)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbbreakable.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3candidates.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty)
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 128.
*************************************************
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-xetex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurosym/eurosym.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grffile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
No file notebook.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def
fontencoding T3 patched
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/size' and I am going to ig
nore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.373 ...back=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]

? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.373 ...back=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]

No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

I'm running jupyter notebook inside a singularity container with CentOS 7.5.
The versions of the jupyter stack are:

- jupyter core     : 4.5.0
- jupyter-notebook : 6.0.0
- qtconsole        : 4.5.3
- ipython          : 7.7.0
- ipykernel        : 5.1.2
- jupyter client   : 5.3.1
- jupyter lab      : not installed
- nbconvert        : 5.6.0
- ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
- nbformat         : 4.4.0
- traitlets        : 4.3.2

I installed all avaible texlive packages in the CentOs7, but the error persist.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you show the content of `./notebook.tex`? texlive2013 looks very old. If you install vanilla texlive from tug.org, you can get texlive2019

Comment: I'll try to install newer version of texlive. This version is te standard version in CentOS 7.5

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: In CentOS 7.9, it is still texlive2013, and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the outdated version of `tcolorbox` installed by CentOS 7.

I encountered the same problem on CentOS 7.8:

- `sudo yum list texlive-tcolorbox` reveals that CentOS 7.8 installs [version `svn29372.2.02-56` of `tcolorbox`](https://rhel.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/texlive-tcolorbox-svn29372.2.02-56.el7.noarch.rpm.html) . This stands for version 2.02 (from 2013/03/13)
- In the latest version of `tcolorbox`, it appears the `tcb/size` choice is defined [here](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/9bf2bc375d008ed832a26fd9cf2fb12f01143570/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty#L836-L847). I do not find this definition in the source code of version 2.02. The [changelog](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/master/doc/latex/tcolorbox/CHANGES.md) does not mention when this was introduced. Looking through the history of the repository on Github, it must have been introduced before the start of the git history at version 3.05 (and I did not find the SVN).

The problem can be "fixed" by downloading version `3.96` of `tcolorbox` from  https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/releases/tag/v3.96 and copying it over the texlive installation under `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox` (later versions of `tcolorbox` introduce other unmet dependencies).